# How to display opening times?

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, logic

I'm trying to show intervals of working hours/days it's should look like this:

[image: Opening Times]
<sub>(source: [clip2net.com](http://clip2net.com/clip/m12007/1247254068-clip-64kb.png))</sub>

I have table where I'm storing day number, open time and closing time **for each day**

[image: table]
<sub>(source: [clip2net.com](http://clip2net.com/clip/m12007/1247253580-clip-4kb.png))</sub>

Then I created query=>

```
var groups = from s in this.OpenTimes
orderby s.Day
group s by new { s.Till, s.Start } into gr
select new
{
    Time = gr.Key.Start + "-" + gr.Key.Till,
    Days = this.OpenTimes
        .Where(o => o.Start == gr.Key.Start && o.Till == gr.Key.Till)
        .OrderBy(d => d.Day).Select(d => d.Day).ToArray()
};
```

This query provides all grouped time intervals and days that included to this time-range
But I faced with problem - I created second half that representing this groups, but it's not working properly.
Maybe somebody could explain to me needed point of vision or this basic logic of showing opening times.

Thanks in advice...

Comment: I'm not sure what "I created second half that representing thsi groups," means.  Are you saying that code you haven't shown isn't working as you expect it to?  Is this a UI question?

Comment: Yes code that I made not working => and I'm not showing this code. This is UI question with elements of logic

Comment: i am curious what would be the ui for saving open close hours. using all textbox ,dropdown , grid or combination of grid/textbox/dropdown?

Answer (score 1):

Next approach works for me:

[result screen](http://clip2net.com/clip/m12007/1247988801-clip-41kb.png)

```
  public string OpeningTimesString
      {
         get
         {
            if (!this.OpeningTimes.IsLoaded)
               this.OpeningTimes.Load();
            var groups = (from s in this.OpeningTimes
                       orderby s.Day, s.Start, s.Stop
                       group s by new { Stop = formatTime(s.Stop), Start = formatTime(s.Start), s.Day } into gr
                       select new
                       {
                          Time = gr.Key.Start + "-" + gr.Key.Stop,
                          Day = gr.Key.Day
                       }).ToList();
            string result = "";
            int tmp = 1;
            for (int i = 0; i < groups.Count(); i++)
            {


               //One one = new One();
               bool exit = false;
               tmp = i;
               while (exit == false)
               {
                  if (i + 1 < groups.Count && groups[i].Time.Equals(groups[i + 1].Time))
                  {
                     i++;
                  }
                  else
                  {
                     if (tmp != i)
                        result += (NormalDayOfWeek)(groups[tmp].Day - 1) + "-" + (NormalDayOfWeek)(groups[i].Day - 1) + " : " + groups[i].Time + "<br />";
                     else
                        result += (NormalDayOfWeek)(groups[i].Day - 1) + " : " + groups[i].Time + "<br />";
                     exit = true;
                  }
               }
            }

            if (result.IsNotNull())
               return result;
            else
               return "[%Not yet defined]";
         }
      }
```